# passing double quote as parameter in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing, python-3.7, double-quotes

I have below part of my Python code where i am trying to pass parameter as double quote in "ID" but its not working:

```
 "ExtractionRequest": {
        "@odata.type": "#TRP.ExtractionRequests",
        "IList": {
            "@odata.type": "#TRP.Extractions.ExtractionRequests.IList",
            "IDList": [{
                "ID": '"'+str(sys.argv[1])+'"',
                "IDType": "TK"
            }]
        }
```

The program runs when i run the code by manually passing the "ID" as "FPOD" but i want to pass the double quote value as parameter.

Comment: Why do you think you need to add double quotes?

Comment: Quotes are only need for string literals, not when you're getting the string from data.

Comment: how does it work then ?

Comment: Just use `"ID": sys.argv[1],`.

Comment: And everything in `sys.argv` is a string, you don't need to call `str()`.

Comment: thanks...but now i am running the code as   xxx.py "FPOD"   and what if i want to run the code as xxx.py FPOD ? Is it possible to handle this in code ?

Comment: If you are talking about `xxx.py "FPOD"` from the *shell*, then that's equivalent to `xxx.py FPOD`. The quotes are not part of the argument, only part of the shell command line that *produces* an argument of `FPOD`.

Comment: i am running the code in pycharm terminal and also in normal windows terminal ..

Comment: Either way, you only need quotes around a command-line argument if it contains special characters. And it doesn't matter inside the script. A string is a single value. Quotes are part of program syntax, not data.

Comment: You seem to be confused about how parameters are processed. It doesn't substitute the value into the source code and then execute that.

Comment: I understood now thanks for the knowledge ..

Comment: can i ask one more question might be related to this. I have for example in my same code i want to always put the date as sysdate-1 and keep the the other value as it is T1200:00.000Z...how to do it ?                           
   "QueryStartDate": "2021-09-02T12:00:00.000Z"              should looks like     
    "QueryStartDate": "2021-09-01T12:00:00.000Z"